# Using Permutations to create numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I'm a high school math teacher working on a simple high school math problem involving permutations.  I like to try to check answers to some of these problems since it helps "convince" the students that the methods actually work, and it helps me develop my limited Mathematica skills just a bit...

here is the question

How many even numbers of at most three digits can be formed using the digits 0,1,2,3, 4 and 5 without repetition?  (I got the answer 68 ways)

Sorry,  I meant... I got the answer 68 numbers,  using regular "mathematical methods",  and I wanted to confirm using Mathematica!

I'm asking just to hopefully learn how to better use Mathematica.

I have the following line which I understand,  but it's just part of the solution, and I wondered how to eliminate the values less than 10  (without using another Select, which is what I did but it seemed really messy)

Again, sorry... I assumed I had to get the answer in three steps.. this was the step for "two digit numbers",   but I already see one answer that gets the result in one line
(I knew there would be nice ways...)

```
Select[FromDigits /@ Permutations[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2}], EvenQ]
```

I figure there must be some clever ways to do this and hoping a few people might share and it would give me some examples to chew on.

Comment: "I got the answer 68 ways" is an ambiguous statement. Believe it or not, I first inferred (what I think was) the incorrect meaning.

Comment: What's wrong with numbers smaller than 10?

Comment: Depends on what the underlying question is. If you must use three of the digits then "without repetition" excludes both those and two digit numbers ending in 0. Whether this is the correct interpretation is unclear.

Comment: Actually there are currently two answers "that gets the result in one line..." - plus Mr. Wizard's comment. What do you want? 68? Wrong, because you want "to eliminate the values less than 10." 65? (@ybeltukov's answer minus three). 60?

Comment: I am really sorry my question was not clear.  In that line I was using Mathematica to try,  TRY,  to find numbers that worked,  but I figured they were supposed to be the values with 2 digits, so not less than 10.  It indicates my lack of skill using Mathematica.  I do in fact want ALL the possible answers , which includes 1, 2 and 3 digits, and I think the answer is in fact 68.  I appreciate all the answers given!

Answer (score 9):

The shortest solution I found:

```
Select[Range[0,999], # ⋂ Range[0, 5] == Sort@# &@IntegerDigits@# && EvenQ@# &]
```

> {0,2,4,10,12,14,20,24,30,32,34,40,42,50,52,54,102,104,120,124,130,132,134,140,142,150,152,154,204,210,214,230,234,240,250,254,302,304,310,312,314,320,324,340,342,350,352,354,402,410,412,420,430,432,450,452,502,504,510,512,514,520,524,530,532,534,540,542}

There are 68 numbers exactly. Here `# ⋂ Range[0, 5] == Sort@# &` check that all digits are in the set `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` and there is no repetitions simultaneously.

Comment: +1 But: "I wondered how to eliminate the values less than 10 (without using another Select)"

Comment: @Eldo - eliminating numbers less than 100 (vice less than 10): `Select[Range[0, 999], # \[Intersection] Range[0, 5] == Sort@# &@IntegerDigits@# && EvenQ@# && Length@IntegerDigits@# == 3 &]` gives 52 numbers

Comment: @Eldo - for eliminating numbers less than 10: `Select[Range[0, 999], # \[Intersection] Range[0, 5] == Sort@# &@IntegerDigits@# && EvenQ@# && Length@IntegerDigits@# > 1 &]` gives 65 numbers

Comment: I appreciate your answer,  totally different approach.    I did want 68,  my questions was badly worded.  I know the end of that command is something I need to learn more about... not using Mathematica a lot, it's concise and probably clear,  but I can't navigate all the @# && once it gets beyond a certain level!  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @TomDeVries There is an equivalent form: `Cases[Range[0, 999], x_ /; Module[{id = IntegerDigits[x]}, id ⋂ Range[0, 5] == Sort[id] && EvenQ[x]]]`. However I recommend you to read [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/4678). It is a really fun part of *Mathematica* which allows you to write a very compact code.

Comment: +1 Nice. You could count count in twos and eliminate the `EvenQ` test for even shorter code `Select[Range[0,999,2],#⋂0~Range~5==Sort@#&@*IntegerDigits]`

Answer (score 7):

```
Cases[Union[FromDigits /@ Permutations[Range[0, 5], {2, 3}]], n_?EvenQ /; n >= 10]
```

> ```
> {10, 12, 14, 20, 24, 30, 32, 34, 40, 42, 50, 52, 54, 102, 104, 120, 124, 130, 132, 134, 140, 142, 
>  150, 152, 154, 204, 210, 214, 230, 234, 240, 250, 254, 302, 304, 310, 312, 314, 320, 324, 340, 
>  342, 350, 352, 354, 402, 410, 412, 420, 430, 432, 450, 452, 502, 504, 510, 512, 514, 520, 524, 
>  530, 532, 534, 540, 542}
> ```

```
Length@%
```

> ```
> 65
> ```

---

**Edit** based on the clarification by the OP:

```
Select[Union[FromDigits /@ Permutations[Range[0, 5], 3]], EvenQ]
```

> ```
> {0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 24, 30, 32, 34, 40, 42, 50, 52, 54, 102, 104, 120, 124, 130, 132, 134, 
>  140, 142, 150, 152, 154, 204, 210, 214, 230, 234, 240, 250, 254, 302, 304, 310, 312, 314, 320, 
>  324, 340, 342, 350, 352, 354, 402, 410, 412, 420, 430, 432, 450, 452, 502, 504, 510, 512, 514, 
>  520, 524, 530, 532, 534, 540, 542}
> ```

```
Length@%
```

> ```
> 68
> ```

Or

```
Cases[Union[FromDigits /@ Permutations[Range[0, 5], 3]], _?EvenQ]//Length
```

> ```
> 68
> ```

Comment: I agree with your excellent answer. As the question is posed the only correct result is 65 :)

Comment: I will admit to a poorly worded question.  As I understand it, the answer is 68, and this answer was helpful,  I did this...  it works for me, I understand it, and I learned something from the n_? pattern which I am unfamiliar with, thank you                                   Cases[Union[FromDigits /@ Permutations[Range[0, 5], 3]], 
  n_?EvenQ] // Length

Comment: @TomDeVries I made an edit based on your comment. For `Cases` there is no `n` needed in `n_?EvenQ`, if you don't use it for further pattern matching.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select[FromDigits /@ Permutations[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}], EvenQ] // Length
```

> 60

**Update** based upon OP's comment to ybeltukov's answer:

```
Union @ Select[Flatten @ Map[FromDigits,
   Map[Permutations[Range @ 6 - 1, {#}] &, Range @ 3], {2}], EvenQ] // Length
```

> 68

Comment: There are `Binomial[6, 3] 3!` == 120 total permutations, and half of the original digits are odd.  I wonder where the supposed remaining eight would be hiding. :^)  (i.e. I agree with this answer.)

Comment: Eliminating numbers less than 100: `Select[FromDigits /@ Permutations[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}], EvenQ@# && Length@IntegerDigits@# == 3 &] // Length` gives 52

Comment: You are missing out all even two digit numbers with a `0` as the last digit.

Comment: ...and 1 digit numbers, but I blame that on my poorly worded question,  thank you for this answer

Answer (score 1):

"From first principles :) ", all integer with *three* different digits

```
SetAttributes[inRange, Listable];
inRange[x_] := Or @@ Array[x == # &, 6, 0];
evenQ@c_ := IntegerPart[c/2] == c/2
sols = {a, b, c} /.  Solve[a != 0 && c != a != b && And @@ inRange@{a, b, c} && evenQ@c, {a, b, c}]

Grid@Map[FromDigits, GatherBy[sols, First], {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]